# How do I automate iCal to export all of my calendars to a specific location using Applescript?

Tags: applescript, icalendar

I'm not too familiar with Applescript, and I'm wondering if there's a way to do this... Is there a way to have iCal export each one of my calendars to a specific location?
I can count the number of calendars I have in iCal and I can loop through them and want to do this task for each calendar... But, I'm not sure how to use Applescript to export each calendar and save it in a specific location. Any tips?

Comment: can we see the code you have already,please ? if you haven't already make sure you look at the dictionary for iCal

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the dictionary and export is accessible via applescript so the only other option would be GUI scripting. so I did a search to see if anyone else had this same thought and sure enough i found [this post](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=296233)

HTH